# Most efficient way to join "most recent row"

Tags: mysql, sql, join, query-optimization

I know this question has been asked 100 times, and this isn't a "how do I do it", but an efficiency question - a topic I don't know much about.

From my internet reading I have settled on one way of solving the most recent problem that sounds like it's pretty efficient - LEFT JOIN a "max" table (grouped by the matching conditions) and then LEFT JOIN the row that matches the grouped conditions. Something like this:

```
 Select employee.*, evaluation.* form employee 
 LEFT JOIN (select max(report_date) report_date, employee_id 
      from evaluation group by employee_id) most_recent_eval 
    on most_recent_eval.employee_id = employee.id
 LEFT JOIN evaluation 
    on evaluation.employee_id = employee.id and evaluation.report_date = most_recent_eval.report_date
```

Are there problems with this that I don't know about? Is this doing 2 table scans (one to find the max, and one to find the row)? Does it have to do 2 full scans for every employee?

The reason I'm asking is that I am now looking at joining on 3 tables where I need the most recent row (evaluations, security clearance, and project) and it seems like any inefficiencies are going to be massively multiplied.

Can anyone give me some advice on this?

Comment: You can find out what the query is doing by running an `explain select ...` query. There is a detailed guidance on MySQL's website how to interpret the results. Without the explain output we cannot tell how efficient your query is.

Comment: This is a simplified example and I'm trying not to cloud the issue with output from my actual queries which contain lots of irrelevant columns. I'm really looking for some more general guidance on the efficiency of various methods of solving the "most recent" join. I will crack open the books on the explain output now, so thank-you for that pointer.

Comment: From looking at the explain results, it appears my subquery to get the most recent eval is doing a cartesian join (shows ALL under the join type) for a derived table. I have an index on the start_date - shouldn't that be used?

Comment: I updated my answer to address this comment about your index.

Comment: Get rid of `LEFT` unless you need it.  It could be getting in the way of performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be in pretty good shape with the query pattern you propose.

One possible suggestion, that will help if your `evaluation` table has its own autoincrementing `id` column.   You *may* be able to find the latest evaluation for each employee with this subquery:

```
            SELECT MAX(id) id
              FROM evaluation
             GROUP BY employee_id
```

Then your join can look like this:

```
        FROM employee
   LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT MAX(id) id
                 FROM evaluation
                GROUP BY employee_id
             ) most_recent_eval ON most_recent_eval.employee_id=employee.id
   LEFT JOIN evaluation ON most_recent_eval.id = evaluation.id
```

This will work if your `id` values and your `report_date` values in your `evaluation` table are in the same order. Only you know if that's the case in your application. But if it is, this is a very helpful optimization.

Other than that, you may need to add some compound indexes to some tables to speed up your queries. Get them working correctly first.  Read http://use-the-index-luke.com/ . Remember that lots of single-column indexes are generally harmful to MySQL query performance unless they're chosen to accelerate particular queries.

If you create a compound index on `(employee_id, report_date)`, this subquery

```
 select max(report_date) report_date, employee_id 
   from evaluation
  group by employee_id
```

can be satisfied with an astonishingly efficient [loose index scan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html).  Similarly, if you're using InnoDB, the query

```
            SELECT MAX(id) id
              FROM evaluation
             GROUP BY employee_id
```

can be satisfied by a loose index scan on a single-column index on `employee_id`.  (If you're using MyISAM, you need a compound index on `(employee_id, id)` because InnoDB puts the primary key column implicitly into every index.)

Comment: When you get this working, please consider asking another question about query performance if you still need help. Please read this first, especially the part on query performance.    http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/

Comment: I don't know the evaluations are being entered in order, so I can't use the ID, but I am using timestamps (in an int(11) column) for numeric sorting. I am reading on use-the-index-luke.com right now.. thanks. I will add more detail in future performance questions as suggested in the link you provided. I guess I was looking for a more general "right direction" answer because I have a lot of new queries to write using the new date-based table structure I am using.

Comment: You should know that `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` data items are just as good for indexing as integers, There's no need to perform unnatural acts on your time/date values to get good indexing and ordering performance.